# Javascript that randomly chooses x of y divs to display in a random order

Tags: javascript, html, random

If i have 10 divs and i want to choose 5 of them randomly and display them in a random order, how can i do that?

This is what im currently using: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/randomcontentorder.htm

Comment: The DIVs are on the web-page?

Comment: how are you rendering the div's in your output? aka, are you generating them via javascript, or are they delivered in the response from the server?

Comment: Also, pure JavaScript? (No library?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display X divs randomly out of a possible Y](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497761/display-x-divs-randomly-out-of-a-possible-y) -- though I don't recommend to extend `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the ten divs in an array, shuffle the array, and show the first five.

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/suJcN/

Answer (score 0):

You can name your divs some kind like `myDiv_0` to `myDiv_9`. Then you can generate random numbers between with JavaScript using `var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10)`. And after that you can get your div by `window.getElementById('myDiv_' + randomnumber)`.