# How would you keep a Math.random() in javascript from picking the same numbers multiple times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random, for-loop

I have an array `var words = []//lots of different words in it`. I have a `Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)` that chooses a random word from the array. This is run in a loop that runs for a random number of times (between 2 and 200 times). I would like to make sure that the random numbers do not get chosen more than once during the time that that loop runs. How would you suggest doing this?

Comment: Can't you just shuffle the array instead and just iterate over it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate 8 unique random numbers between 1 and 100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-8-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Ah... Thanks, for some reason I did not think of that. That sounds like the right thing to do. Thanks

Comment: yeah. That would be a better solution

Comment: Posted an answer instead of just a comment.

Comment: untill you will find a good solution you can remove from the aray or its copy the last used value and put the last value of the array one instead. than you will be left with n-1 options and using randon(n-1) - you will get an unchosen value. (you should keep a variable -lastIndex)

Comment: You can move the random on picking a prime number < than the length of your dataset and use modulo to loop over them. See my response below.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's multiple ways of doing this.

You can shuffle the entire collection, and just grab items from one end. This will ensure you won't encounter any one item more than once (or rather, more than the number of times it occured in the original input array) during one whole iteration.

This, however, requires you to either modify in-place the original collection, or to create a copy of it.

If you only intend to grab a few items, there might be a different way.

You can use a hash table or other type of dictionary, and just do a check if the item you picked at random in the original collection already exists in the dictionary. If it doesn't, add it to the dictionary and use it. If it already exists in the dictionary, pick again.

This approach uses storage proportional to the number of items you need to pick.

Also note that this second approach is a bit bad performance-wise when you get to the few last items in the list, as you can risk hunting for the items you still haven't picked for quite a number of iterations, so this is only a viable solution if the items you need to randomly pick are far fewer than the number of items in the collection.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand it. I would need to execute it to see how it operates.

Answer (score 3):

There are several different approaches, which are more or less effective depending on how much data you have, and how many items you want to pick:

- Remove items from the array once they have been picked.
- Shuffle the array and get the first items.
- Keep a list of picked items and compare against new picks.
- Loop through the items and pick values randomly based on the probability to be picked.

Comment: Good reply. Better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

I'd shuffle the array as follows and then iterate over the shuffled array. There's no expensive array `splice` calls and the shuffling routine consists of swapping two values in the array `n` times where `n` is the length of the array, so it should scale well:

```
function shuffle(arr) {
    var shuffled = arr.slice(0), i = arr.length, temp, index;
    while (i--) {
        index = Math.floor(i * Math.random());
        temp = shuffled[index];
        shuffled[index] = shuffled[i];
        shuffled[i] = temp;
    }
    return shuffled;
}

console.log(shuffle(["one", "two", "three", "four"]));
```

Answer (score 3):

this is how you can do it *without* shuffling the whole array

```
a = "abcdefghijklmnopq".split("");
c = 0;
r = [];

do {
   var len = a.length - c;
   var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
   r.push(a[rnd]);
   a[rnd] = a[len - 1];
} while(++c < 5);

console.log(r);
```

the idea is to pick from `0..(length - step)` elements and then shift the picked element towards the end.

Comment: My answer does pretty much that, although yours seems a little neater, and is more flexible in that you can choose to only shuffle a subset of the array... OK, yours is better. +1.

Comment: You might want a `var` statement for `a`, `c` and `r` though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try using a map (`Object` literal) instead of an `Array` with keys being indexes:

```
var words = [ /* ... */ ] , map = { } , length = words.length ;
for(var n = 0 ; n < length ; n++) map[n] = words[n] ;
```

then make a function to pick a random entry based on the length, delete the entry (hence the index) and adjust the length:

```
function pickRandomEntry() {

    var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * length ) ;

    var entry = map[random] ;

        delete map[random] ;
        length-- ;

    return entry ;

}
```

with this approach, you have to check for an `undefined` return value (since `random` might return the same number) and run the function again until it returns an actual value; or, make an array of picked indexes to filter the random numbers (which will however slow performance in case of long iteration cycles).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this.

What you could do is use .splice() on your array to remove the item which is hit by words.

Then you can iterate over your array until it's empty. If you need to keep the array pristine you can create a copy of it first and iterate over the copy.

```
var words = ['apple', 'banana', 'cocoa', 'dade', 'elephant'];
while (words.length > 0) {
    var i    = Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length);
    var word = words.splice(i, 1)[0];
}
```

Or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with prime numbers and modulo that seems to do the trick without moving the original array or adding a hash:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="javascript:" onclick="shuffle(['48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64','65','66','67','68','69','70','71','72','73','74','75','76','77','78','79','80','81','82','83','84','85','86','87','88','89','90','91','92','93','94','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','95','96','97','98','99'])">shuffle</a>
 <div id="res"></div>
 <script>
    function shuffle(words){
        var l = words.length,i = 1,primes = [43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79],//add more if needed
        prime = primes[parseInt(Math.random()*primes.length, 10)],
        temp = [];
        do{
            temp.push((i * prime) % l);
        }while(++i <= l);
        console.log(temp.join(','));
        console.log(temp.sort().join(','));
    }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a question: how does this protect against multiple access to the same entry?

Comment: It loops the number of items times, and as the increment is a prime number it never fell at the same position on that loop. I removed some prime numbers as they were too small or too big.

Comment: I see. This part `temp.push( (i * prime) % l )` is clever. Creative use of `Math` and `modulus`. Still, as there is no function to create a Set of prime numbers, this isn't really apt for indefinite iteration, is it?

Comment: Yep, but if you know more or less the size of your dataset, you can take a set of primes around the mid size, and check if there is enough randomness.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the prime number you pick is relative prime to the length of the list. What if the prime you pick is 59, and the list contains 59 elements? Wouldn't you then pick the same one each time?

Comment: Also, you need to be extra careful when selecting which prime numbers to put into the candidate list, otherwise you'll have elements in the input that can never be chosen at all.

Comment: Yeah, you need to pick the primes around the middle of the size, like in my final code. But it was interesting to see.

Comment: -1 On the right track, but I would just pick a random number coprime to `l` (this is easy enough). I'd also recommend starting with a random `i`, and upgrading to a linear congruential generator (which is much more random for little extra cost).