# Getting random unique from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo. How can I get ONLY unique selection(s) from the array of cars

```js
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
for ( var i = 0,l = cars.length; i <random; i++ ) {
   var item = cars[Math.floor(Math.random()*cars.length)];
   console.log(item);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: shuffle the array, then pop them off

Comment: how many items do you want returned ?

Comment: This has been asked many times before in all kinds of variations. Please have a look at https://www.google.com/search?q=unique+random+values+array+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: `function randommInt(min, max){
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
console.log(cars[randommInt(0, cars.length- 1)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing this as a generator makes it pretty nice to work with. Note, this implementation differs from ones that require the entire input array to be shuffled first.

> This `sample` function works lazily, giving you **1** random item per iteration up to `N` items you ask for. This is nice because if you just want **3** items from a list of **1000**, you don't have to touch all 1000 items first.

```js
// sample :: Integer -> [a] -> [a]
const sample = n => function* (xs) {
  let ys = xs.slice(0);
  let len = xs.length;
  while (n > 0 && len > 0) {
    let i = (Math.random() * len) >> 0;
    yield ys.splice(i,1)[0];
    n--; len--;
  }
}

// example inputs
let items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
let numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// get 3 random items
for (let i of sample(3) (items))
  console.log(i); // f g c

// partial application
const lotto = sample(3);
for (let i of lotto(numbers))
  console.log(i); // 3 8 7

// shuffle an array
const shuffle = xs => Array.from(sample (Infinity) (xs))
console.log(shuffle(items)) // [b c g f d e a]
```

I chose to implement `sample` in a way that does not mutate the input array, but you could easily argue that a mutating implementation is favourable.

For example, the `shuffle` function might wish to mutate the original input array. Or you might wish to sample from the same input at various times, updating the input each time.

```js
// sample :: Integer -> [a] -> [a]
const sample = n => function* (xs) {
  let len = xs.length;
  while (n > 0 && len > 0) {
    let i = (Math.random() * len) >> 0;
    yield xs.splice(i,1)[0];
    n--; len--;
  }
}

// deal :: [Card] -> [Card]
const deal = xs => Array.from(sample (2) (xs));

// setup a deck of cards (13 in this case)
// cards :: [Card]
let cards = 'A234567890JQK'.split('');

// deal 6 players 2 cards each
// players :: [[Card]]
let players = Array.from(Array(6), $=> deal(cards))

console.log(players);
// [K, J], [6, 0], [2, 8], [Q, 7], [5, 4], [9, A]

// `cards` has been mutated. only 1 card remains in the deck
console.log(cards);
// [3]
```

`sample` is no longer a **pure** function because of the array input mutation, but in certain circumstances (demonstrated above) it might make more sense.

---

Another reason I chose a generator instead of a function that just returns an array is because you may want to continue sampling until some specific condition.

Perhaps I want the first prime number from a list of 1,000,000 random numbers.

- *"How many should I sample?"* – you don't have to specify
- *"Do I have to find all the primes first and then select a random prime?"* – Nope.

Because we're working with a generator, this task is trivial

```
const randomPrimeNumber = listOfNumbers => {
  for (let x of sample(Infinity) (listOfNumbers)) {
    if (isPrime(x))
      return x;
  }
  return NaN;
}
```

This will continuously sample 1 random number at a time, `x`, check if it's prime, then return `x` if it is. If the list of numbers is exhausted before a prime is found, `NaN` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Simple code.

```js
var random = 0, cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"], newCars = [];

while (newCars.length < 3) {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  if (newCars.indexOf(cars[random]) == -1) {
    newCars.push(cars[random]);
  }
}

console.log(newCars);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function RandomUnique(inputArray){
  var ia = inputArray;
  if(!(ia instanceof Array)){
    throw new Error('inputArray must be an instanceof Array');
  }
  this.unique = function(){
    return ia.splice(Math.random()*ia.length, 1)[0];
  }
  this.getArray = function(){
   return ia;
  }
}
var ru = new RandomUnique(yourArray);
console.log(ru.unique());
console.log(ru.unique());
```