# JavaScript: Random number in Loop

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I can make a JavaScript loop that have to guess a correct number, 1-500.

Every loop there should be a new unique number that hasn't been guessed before. However it should guess in a random order.

Yes:

> 351, 201, 97 ...

No:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 ...

**My code so far:**

```
var number;

setInterval(function(){

number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
console.log(number);

if (number == 350) {
console.log("Correct Number!")
}
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Create an array that has every number in the range, shuffle the array, read out the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate unique random numbers between 1 and 100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to store the numbers you have already randomed.
If you encountered a number you have already randomed, random again.

```
var usedNumbers = [];
var interval = setInterval(function(){

    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;

    while(usedNumbers.includes(number)){
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
    }
    usedNumbers.push(number);
    if (number == 350){
        console.log("Correct Number!");
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    console.log(number);
}, 500)
```

Comment: This is heavily inefficient as like the op described "Every loop there should be a new unique number" Within you solution non unique numbers can be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at solving your problem using a fisher yates shuffle on an array with all numbers between 500.

```
var number = 121;

var numbArr = [];

for(var x = 1; x <= 500; x++){
  numbArr.push(x);
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

shuffle(numbArr);

for(var x = 0; x < numbArr.length; x++){
  if(number == numbArr[x]){
        console.log("Found number at entry " + x);
  }
}
```

The guessing with a random number comes by using the shuffle of all the possible numbers which means that it shall not be guessed again.