# How do I make sure there are no repeated numbers when using random()?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, numbers, repeat

I have this code that displays 100 random numbers, then adds a break for every 10 numbers. How would I ensure that these 100 random numbers do not have repeats? I know maybe there's something to do with more if statements?

Thanks,
J

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <h1><font color = "blue">Random Numbers and Breaks (for loops)</font></h1> 
  <p><font color="red">This will display 100 numbers and insert a break in 10-number intervals:</font></p>
  <div id="demo"> </div>
  <body>
    <script> 
      var text= '';
      var i = 0;
      var counter = 0;

      for (; i < 100; i++ , counter++) { 
      var numbers = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      text += numbers + "  " + "<br>";
      if (i % 10 === 9) {
          text += "<br>";
      }
    }        
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may have a look into shuffling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array

Comment: Tip: `if( i % 10 === 9 )` does the same thing as those 10 separate if statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate unique random numbers between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that saved a lot of useless codes. But that possibly duplicate still doesn't tell me how I can prevent these 100 numbers from being the same?

Comment: If you're looking for 100 non-repeating numbers that go from 1-100 just shuffle. Otherwise you'll need to track used numbers to see if you have a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, if you don't know what something does, please research it. Do not simply copy and paste.

```js
      var text= '';
      var i = 0;
      var counter = 0;
      var nums = []; // Created array
      var numbers;
      for (; i < 100; i++ , counter++) { 
        numbers = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        while (nums.includes(numbers))
          numbers = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        // While nums array includes numbers, reroll.
        nums.push(numbers); // Push the number to the array
        text += numbers + "  " + "<br>";
        if (i % 10 === 9) text += "<br>"
      // If the rightmost digit is a 9, add the br tag
    }        
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <h1><font color = "blue">Random Numbers and Breaks (for loops)</font></h1> 
  <p><font color="red">This will display 100 numbers and insert a break in 10-number intervals:</font></p>
  <div id="demo"> </div>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How would I ensure that these 100 random numbers do not have repeats?

You need to save returned values (by random number generator) so that same value is not returned again.

```
function randomNumberGenerator( min, max )
{
   var returnedValues = [];
   return function()
   {
       var num = null;
       while( num == null ||  returnedValues.indexOf( num ) != -1 )
       {
           num  = Math.floor((Math.random() * (max-min)) + min);
       }
       return num;
   }
}
```

Now you can call this `n` number of times *( n < (max - min) )*

```
var nRandomNumbers = 10;
var randomNumArr = [];
var ran1 = randomNumberGenerator(1,100); //initialize the randomNumberGenerator
for( var counter = 0; counter < nRandomNumbers; counter++ )
{
  randomNumArr.push( ran1() );
}
```

Comment: For 100 numbers from 1-100 just shuffle.

Comment: @DaveNewton If OP is looking to fetch 100 numbers from 1 to 100, then I agree with you. However, OP has mentioned *How would I ensure that these 100 random numbers do not have repeats?* OP didn't said that those 100 necessarily have to be *n* to *n + 100*.

Comment: 100 numbers from 1-100 was just an example, I would use this if I needed 100 numbers from say 1-500 right?

Comment: You can also use this if you want to get 100 from 1-100, though this wouldn't be the best approach for that requirement - **shuffling** would be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fischer yates algorithm for shuffling an array and shuffle an array from 1 to 100.

```
// Returns num size random array from 1 to num
function getRandomArray(num) {
  const arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    arr.push(i+1);
  }
  let temp, rIndex;
  // swap random element
  for (i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    rIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[rIndex];
    arr[rIndex] = temp;
  }

  return arr;
}

let text = '';
getRandomArray(100).forEach(function(item, index){
  text += item + " <br />";
  text += (index + 1)%10 === 0 ? "<br />" : "";
});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: A shortcut for making an array of numbers, 0-n, is using `[...Array(n).keys()]`

Comment: Don't most browsers support it? You are correct about it being confusing though.