# Math.random() running multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a random image generator, which needs to display 14 random images.
This works, however those 14 random images are being replaced with others 3 times in a call.

I don't want this to happen, but I have no clue on how to stop this. I think that math.random() is causing the issue, but I'm not sure. I am running this script on **React.JS**

My code:

```
for (var g=0; g < 14; g++) {
    var rdmNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1;
    var imgName = "img_" + rdmNumber +".png";
    var src = "img" + "/" + imgName;
    indents.push(<div className="item-picture" key={c}><img src= {src8}className="item-img" alt="Your possible winnings" /></div>);
}
```

The indents.push is the output of my call, which is being displayed as followed:

```
{indents}
```

.gif from what is happening:
https://gyazo.com/c576c52a90843a9ab055790610303fe4

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I don't need unique images, I just want them to stay the same, and not replace as seen in the .gif

Comment: I don't think this code is quite enough for us to help you. Can you show more of the relevant code?

Comment: Isn't it possible for `Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1` to return the same value more than once, even though you execute it multiple times? E.g., the random sequence could be `4 1 7 3 6 3 8 12 9`, which as you can see already "replaces" one of your images with image 3. Have you tried creating an array from 1 to 14, and then randomly sampling from that array without replacement? This might be what you want. Or you could create an array 1 to 14, shuffle it, then just iterate through normally, thus simulating randomness by doing the shuffle.

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Comment: @Tholle I now included the part which outputs the images. That's all I have

@G

Comment: @gaetanoM I don't need unique images, I just want them to stay the same, and not replace as seen in the .gif

Comment: @CoreyLevinson Your last suggestion sounds good, although I have no idea how to make something like that.

Comment: @Kipcarry See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array

Answer (score 1):

You might have written this code inside render function which will run every time there is some change.

Try to write this code in componentWillMount.

Comment: I tried, however when I do so it says {indents} is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is create an array of random images once, outside of render, and then render that.

Do it outside of the component, or in the constructor.

```
// outside of your component
let images = []
for (var g=0; g < 14; g++) {
    var rdmNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1;
    var imgName = "img_" + rdmNumber +".png";
    var src = "img" + "/" + imgName;
    images.push(src);
}

// in your component's render method
images.forEach(url => 
    indents.push(<div className="item-picture" key={url}>
        <img src= {url}className="item-img" alt="Your possible winnings"/>
    </div>)
)

// and you can render {indents} somewhere after that
```

Comment: And how would I achieve that? I am a rookie.

Comment: I forgot to mention how important the {indents} part is. As I call multiple of these functions there name all need to be unique. Do I need to enter 0 -> 14 in the let images array? A little bit more of explanation of how this code works would be appreciated :-).

http://prntscr.com/jysbzh

Comment: that other answer suggested to use componentWillMount, not componentWillUnmount 
I must admit, it's a pretty confusing piece of code you got there.
I'd suggest making it work for one array of indents first. And then extract it into a function instead of copying code over and over.

Comment: This also gives me the following error:   
Line 99:  'map' is not defined       no-undef 
Line 99:  'indents' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I just noticed that too, I made a new componentWillMount (because none existed) and it still gave me the same error I mentioned here above :(

Comment: well, indents need to be defined. I updated my code example again. Try moving the first part outside of your react component (before imports), and the `forEach` part into you render function, where I guess indents is defined.

Comment: Looks like it should work, however imports are obligated to be at the top (http://prntscr.com/jyshfu)

Comment: I meant after imports. It's odd indents is still undefined

Comment: Because we didn't define it yet. I don't know what you meant with images.push(src). But you replaced my indents.push() with that piece of code, that's why it isn't defined. Could I change it?

Comment: oh, well, change it back to `images.push(src)` the way it is in my example. 
Did you get it working?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do I need to do?