# Best approach to random 10 numbers between 1 and 100 no dupes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, random

This has been asked dozens of times, but somehow, after reading many answers, I'm not convinced. I'm not cleared about the best way to do it, performance and code simplicity.

1. Should I set the list [1.. 100] and keep picking random (it will run 10 times) from there to another array, avoiding searching for it every new random?
2. Should I develop and run 10 times (at least) a random function to return a 1.. 100, checking if it is not a dupe and put it into an array?
3. Some Javascript function that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Loop until 10 numbers have been found. For uniqueness, use `Set`.

Comment: @31piy, wow did not know about that!

Comment: No, this question is asking for the best way to do it.

Comment: @Huangism, look at the answsers of each thread.

Comment: @noneJavaScript I don't know what you mean, the answer given generates random unique numbers between 1 and 100

Comment: @Huangism OP doesn't want random unique numbers between 1-100, he wants 10 unique random numbers between 1-100

Comment: @JKimbrough yea I know the answers in the other question does that but with 8 however the method is the same

Answer (score 4):

You can use a while loop to generate random numbers with `Math.random()` and add the numbers to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which contains only unique values.

```js
var randoms = new Set();
while(randoms.size<10){
  randoms.add(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}
console.log([...randoms.values()]);
```

You can also just use an Array and check if the generated random number already exists in it before pushing it to the Array.

```js
var randoms = [];
while(randoms.length<10){
  var random = Math.ceil(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  if(randoms.indexOf(random)==-1){
    randoms.push(random);
  }
}
console.log(randoms);
```

For a more generic function, you can use this:

```
function generateRandoms(min, max, numOfRandoms, unique){
  /*min is the smallest possible generated number*/
  /*max is the largest possible generated number*/
  /*numOfRandoms is the number of random numbers to generate*/
  /*unique is a boolean specifying whether the generated random numbers need to be unique*/
    var getRandom = function(x, y){
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y + 1) + y);
    }
    var randoms = [];
    while(randoms.length<numOfRandoms){
      var random = getRandom(min, max);
      if(randoms.indexOf(random)==-1||!unique){
        randoms.push(random);
      }
    }
    return randoms;
}
```

```js
function generateRandoms(min, max, numOfRandoms, unique){
    var getRandom = function(x, y){
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y + 1) + y);
    }
    var randoms = [];
    while(randoms.length<numOfRandoms){
      var random = getRandom(min, max);
      if(randoms.indexOf(random)==-1||!unique){
        randoms.push(random);
      }
    }
    return randoms;
}
console.log(generateRandoms(1, 100, 10, true));
```

Comment: The Set method is great, but the while loop one is already posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100

Comment: @Huangism, but not the Set method, which is exactly what I was looking for, clean, fast solution. Don't try to close this, StackO, Officer.

Comment: The close votes aren't mine, the other post could use an update as well

Comment: Pedantic note: this should probably use `1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` as `Math.random` _can_ return 0, but never 1

Comment: @searlea Thanks for telling me. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This technique creates N1 numbers (the total range) and shuffles them, then picks the top N2 number (how many we actually want), we'll use Fisher-Yates shuffle.

```js
const n1 = 100;
const n2 = 10;

let pool = [...Array(n1).keys()];

var result = [];

while (result.length < n2) {
   let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * pool.length);
   result = result.concat(pool.splice(index, 1));       
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I prefer using a shuffle, but a real [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) would be the correct way of doing it.

Comment: You're right, I'm actually in the process of updating to use the Fisher-Yates :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var randomArray = [];

while(randomArray.length < 10) {
  var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  if(randomArray.indexOf(random) === -1) {
    randomArray.push(random);
  }
 
}
console.log(randomArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

#2 would be the most efficient.

```js
var nums = []
while(nums.length < 10) {
  var n = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
  if (!nums.includes(n)) nums.push(n);
}
console.log(nums);
```

You could also use `Set` in a newer browser, which would be a little faster than manually checking for existence:

```js
var nums = new Set();
while(nums.size < 10) {
  var n = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
  nums.add(n);
}
console.log([...nums.values()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function adds all numbers from `betweenStart` to `betweenEnd`, randomizes them over `randomRuns` loops and returns a list with `amount` entries:

```js
function randomNumbersBetweenXAndY(betweenStart, betweenEnd, amount, randomRuns) {
    if (betweenStart === void 0) { betweenStart = 0; }
    if (betweenEnd === void 0) { betweenEnd = 100; }
    if (amount === void 0) { amount = 10; }
    if (randomRuns === void 0) { randomRuns = 1; }
    //Verify parameters
    var maxPossibleCandidates = Math.abs(betweenStart - betweenEnd) + 1;
    if (amount > maxPossibleCandidates) {
        console.warn("You cannot get more unique numbers between " + betweenStart + " and " + betweenStart + " than " + maxPossibleCandidates + ". " + amount + " is too many!");
        amount = maxPossibleCandidates;
    }
    //array to return
    var list = [];
    //fill array
    for (var index = betweenStart; index <= betweenEnd; index++) {
        list.push(index);
    }
    //Randomize
    while (randomRuns--) {
        for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
            var tmp = list[index];
            list[index] = list[randomIndex];
            list[randomIndex] = tmp;
        }
    }
    //Return data
    return list.slice(0, amount);
}
//TEST
console.log(randomNumbersBetweenXAndY(1, 100, 10));
```

Comment: This doesn't work..it doesn't produce 10 unique numbers between 1-100