# Generate Unique Numbers in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to javascript and trying to get comfy with `Functions`, `For` loops, and `If` statements. I'm working on a simple exercise that generates 5 random numbers from a function call. One bit of logic that I'm struggling with putting together is comparing the numbers created by Math.random that are pushed into an array. What's the best method to use to ensure that all numbers to push to the array are unique (no duplicates)? Would I add an `If` statement in the `For` codeblock that checks every number, and if they match, rerun the Math.random function? Trying to figure out if that's the best way to approach the problem.

```
function randoNumbers(min, max){

let randomNumbers = [];

for (let counter = 0; counter < 5 ; counter++){
    randomNumbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + +min));
    }
    console.log(randomNumbers);

}

randoNumbers(1, 10);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate unique random numbers between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100

Comment: https://gist.github.com/guilhermepontes/17ae0cc71fa2b13ea8c20c94c5c35dc4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very plain solution would be to generate numbers until the generated number is not already included in the array, and then push it to the result array:

```js
function randoNumbers(min, max) {
  const randomNumbers = [];
  for (let counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
    let num;
    do {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }
    while (randomNumbers.includes(num))
    randomNumbers.push(num);
  }
  console.log(randomNumbers);
}

randoNumbers(1, 10);
```

For slightly better complexity, you could use a `Set` instead (`set.has` is quicker than `arr.includes`):

```js
function randoNumbers(min, max) {
  const set = new Set();
  for (let counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
    let num;
    do {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }
    while (set.has(num))
    set.add(num);
  }
  console.log([...set]);
}

randoNumbers(1, 10);
```

Comment: This is great thank you! So overwhelmed with the fact that there are so many ways to solve this example. What's the best method for selecting the right approach, simplicity or complexity? I'll check out the `includes` function to better understand how the solution works

Comment: It depends on the situation, but ceteris paribus, simple is better, because code readability is one of the most important things to strive for. But, for example, if performance is a significant factor (which it rarely is), more complex code that runs more quickly can be worth it. (make sure to comment liberally if what the code is doing isn't obvious at a glance)

Comment: Although, here I would argue that using a `Set` doesn't make the code any less readable and I would prefer it over using an array.

Comment: @slider Yep, it's not more complicated at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this problem. I am contributing my way of solving it.

```js
function randoNumbers(min, max) {

  let randomNumbers = [];

  for (; randomNumbers.length < 5;) {
    const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + +min);
    if (!randomNumbers.includes(value))
      randomNumbers.push(value);
  }
  console.log(randomNumbers);

}



randoNumbers(1, 10);
```