# Get a unique item from list in react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Here is my list:

```
newdiscoverPlanet: [
  require('../img/sunp.png'),
  require('../img/twopp.png'),
  require('../img/bluep.png'),
  require('../img/purplep.png'),
  require('../img/bluepurplep.png'),
  require('../img/redp.png'),
  require('../img/orangep.png')

],
```

I put all of this into a function then use `Math` here:

```
getRandomPlanet = () =>{
  var planetItem = this.state.newdiscoverPlanet[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.newdiscoverPlanet.length)];
  this.setState({
    changePlanet: planetItem,
  });
}
```

And then I put them into tabs to get a unique image from the list:

```
    _renderTabIndicator() {
       let tabs = [{
               text: `${this.state.tags.toLowerCase()}`,
               iconSource: `${this.state.changePlanet}`
           },{
               text: `${this.state.tags2.toLowerCase()}`,
               iconSource: `${this.state.changePlanet}`
           },{
               text: `${this.state.tags3.toLowerCase()}`,
               iconSource: `${this.state.changePlanet}`
       }];
       return <PagerTabIndicator tabs={tabs} />;
   }
```

But everytime I load the page I get the same image from each source. Is there a way to make them unique? How can I do something like this in React Native:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2380113/9318643

Comment: This is a little confusing.. are you expecting `this.state.changePlanet` to have different values for each tab?

Comment: @azium yes i am

Comment: well that's like saying `var a = 1` then expecting `a` to not equal `1`. You're not setting 3 different values, you're setting a value and using that value 3 times. You don't need any state for this you could just call `this.state.newdiscoverPlanet[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.newdiscoverPlanet.length)]` where `iconSource` is... `iconSource: <put it here>`

Comment: mind you, that will get you different values, not necessarily unique. but you should start there

Comment: But wouldn't there be a chance where the images will be the same as each other in a different iconSource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing the same value (this.state.changePlanet) 3 times and expecting a different result.
I think you just need to make the method **return** a random planet like so:

```
getRandomPlanet = () => {
  return this.state.newdiscoverPlanet[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.newdiscoverPlanet.length)];
}
```

then you can call this 3 times and you will get 3 different images:

```
_renderTabIndicator() {
       let tabs = [{
               text: `${this.state.tags.toLowerCase()}`,
               iconSource: this.getRandomPlanet()
           },{
               text: `${this.state.tags2.toLowerCase()}`,
               iconSource: this.getRandomPlanet()
           },{
               text: `${this.state.tags3.toLowerCase()}`,
               iconSource: this.getRandomPlanet()
       }];
       return <PagerTabIndicator tabs={tabs} />;
   }
```

---

**Edit**: If you want to ensure that no two same planets are chosen, you might do something like this:

```
getRandomPlanets = (n) => {

  // Shuffle array
  const shuffled = this.state.newdiscoverPlanet.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

  // Get sub-array of first n elements after shuffled
  let selected = shuffled.slice(0, n);
  return selected;
}
```

and then to call:

```
_renderTabIndicator() {
  const planets = this.getRandomPlanets(3);
  let tabs = [{
                   text: `${this.state.tags.toLowerCase()}`,
                   iconSource: planets[0]
               },{
                   text: `${this.state.tags2.toLowerCase()}`,
                   iconSource: planets[1]
               },{
                   text: `${this.state.tags3.toLowerCase()}`,
                   iconSource: planets[2]
           }];
           return <PagerTabIndicator tabs={tabs} />;
       }
```