# Unique Random Number Generation JSX

Tags: arrays, reactjs, random, jsx

```js
    const maxNumber = 10;
    const arrayNumber = [];

    for (let i=0; i<10;i++){
      const randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxNumber) + 1);
      arrayNumber.push ( randomNumber )
    }

    console.log(arrayNumber)
```

When I console log arrayNumber it shows some repeated numbers as shown in below screenshot

[Number Repeats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhNMY.png)

How can I generate unique random numbers, please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate unique random numbers between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved my problem:

```
if(arrayNumber.indexOf(randomNumber)==-1){
    arrayNumber.push ( randomNumber )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this one:

```
const maxNumber = 100;
const arrayNumber = ;
for (let i=1; i<=10;i++){
  const randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxNumber) * i);
  arrayNumber.push ( randomNumber )
}
console.log(arrayNumber)
```