# Different random numbers in js

Tags: javascript, html, math, random

How rand!=rand1,rand2,rand3
rand1!=rand2,rand3,rand and ... in this code

```
var rand= Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
var rand1= Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
var rand2= Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
var rand3= Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
```

Comment: Yes, so what is the problem?

Comment: are you trying to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2380019/1358308

Answer (score 1):

Because `random()` is random.
Guess a random number on your mind!
Is it equal to the random number that I guess right now?