# Getting a 40 random values from a JavaScript array, Quizz App. I have in another file questions.js 3000 questions, I want to get random 40 questions

Tags: javascript

I want to get unique random 40 questions from questions.js anyone have suggestions.

```
//show Questions from array 
function showQuetions(index) {
  const que_text = document.querySelector(".que_text");

  //question tag add questions from another file
  let que_tag = '<span>' + questions[index].numb + ". " + questions[index].question + '</span>';
  let option_tag = '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[0] + '</span></div>' +
    '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[1] + '</span></div>' +
    '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[2] + '</span></div>' +
    '<div class="option"><span>' + questions[index].options[3] + '</span></div>';
  que_text.innerHTML = que_tag;
  option_list.innerHTML = option_tag;

  const option = option_list.querySelectorAll(".option");

  for (i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
    option[i].setAttribute("onclick", "optionSelected(this)");

  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem". Currently, this question's title is almost the entire problem, not a summary ;).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate unique random numbers between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Answer (score 0):

The are multiples ways to do that :

### shuffling array

The first method would be to shuffle the array and the take the first 40 questions.

You can write a pretty simple methods that suffle your array [How can I shuffle an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)

### Random elements

You can also take 40 random elements (by taking a random integer between **0** and the number of questions you have and then removing that questions from the array.

Be sure to make a deep copy of the array before doing this

```js
copy = Object.assign([],questions)
```

Then, do not forget to remove the question from the array to ensure not having the same question twice

Here is a snipper with both example :

```js
/**
 * Shuffles array in place.
 * @param {Array} a items An array containing the items.
 * From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array
 */
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

const nbQuestions = 2
const questions = ["question 1","question 2","question 3","question 4","question 5","question 6"]

//method 1 

//deep copy
let method1Questions = Object.assign([],questions)

shuffle(method1Questions)

let randomQuestions1 = method1Questions.slice(0,nbQuestions)

console.log(randomQuestions1)


//method 2 

//deep copy
let method2Questions = Object.assign([],questions)
let randomQuestions2 = []

for (let i=0; i < nbQuestions; i++){
  //random int
  let questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * method2Questions.length)
  randomQuestions2.push(method2Questions[questionIndex])
  method2Questions.splice(questionIndex,1)
}

console.log(randomQuestions2)
```