# generate 4 unique random number in arr?

Tags: javascript

If I want 4 random number in an array [num1, num2, num3, num4], I can't do

```
function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const arr = [getRandomFloat(1,10), getRandomFloat(1,10), getRandomFloat(1,10), getRandomFloat(1,10)]
```

because I'll have duplicated value. Is there any way or library that allow me to generate a unique set of randomed number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate unique random numbers between 1 and 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100)

Comment: No, you won't have duplicated value. Did you try running your code yourself once?

Comment: @KishanKumar really? have you tried running the code *more than once*

Comment: Yes, I did @Bravo

Comment: @KishanKumar - do you think it's at all possible (though highly unlikely) to get the same random number more than once - but I do see your point - didn't realise the numbers were FLOATS rather than integers :p

Comment: @Bravo, that would be totally possible to get the same random number, I don't disagree with that. But I don't see the case here, as I did try running it about 4-5 times to see if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is efficient method to achieve this. You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the random unique numbers in an array

You can even add a check if `unique numbers` are possible or not as

```
  if (max - min < n) return "Not possible";
```

```js
function getRandomNumbers(n, min = 0, max = 0) {
  const set = new Set();
  while (set.size !== n) {
    set.add(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }
  return [...set];
}

console.log(getRandomNumbers(4, 1, 10));
```

Comment: why are you using `Math.floor`? that won't return a "randomFloat"

Comment: @Bravo Thanks I just skipped that part while reading snippet

Comment: set.length doesn't work? why use dot size?

Comment: @Ambrose `set` is not an array so you have to use its `size` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the array as empty and then continue adding values to it until it has 4 numbers.
You can also avoid duplicates by using if condition.

```
function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
    
    var arr=[];
    var min=1, max=10;
    while (arr.length != 4)  // executes loop till length of array is 4
    {
        var i = getRandomFloat(min, max);
        // checking if number already exists in array
        if (arr.includes(i))
        {
            continue;
        }
        arr.push(i);
    }
```