# How to create an N_sized Array with the size of N(x) and fill it with the numbers in a range from 0 to 100 randomly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Hello StackOverflowCommunity! My name is Piet.

While investigating the beloved Javascript I got a bit stuck:

I´m not sure why I get 98 empty items pushed into my Array.

On Index[0] and Index[99] I get IntegerValues as expected.

Thank you for your answers! :)

```
// create an Array with the size of N(x) and 
// fill it with numbers in a range from 0 to 100 randomly.

createNSizedArray = (x) => {

    for(let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        var arr = [];
        arr[i] = arr.push(Math.round(Math.random()*100));
        
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(createNSizedArray(100)); 

// output -> [ 31, <98 empty items>, 1 ];

// Why are the other 98 items in the Array empty and how to change them into integer values?
```

Actually I inspected the Items[1-98] to find out their values and to check if they are really empty.

But:

console.log(arr[4]) for example return "undefined" to me. So they are not really empty.

Comment: take a closer look at `var arr = [];`, there you actually set everything so far to an empty array again on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much  
orustammanapov
! :)) I knew I overlooked something!

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a mostly undefined array because you are defining a new variable `arr` at each iteration. You should move the declaration of `arr` outside of the loop.

Here is a quick alternative: `Array(100).fill().map(_=>Math.round(Math.random()*100))`

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the initialization of the array before the for loop. This makes sure that you don't make a new array every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are creating a new array on each iteration.
Try this:

```
createNSizedArray = (x) => {
  var arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
  }
  return arr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
const createNSizedArray = (x) => {
    // it had to be moved outside the for-loop to prevent from setting everything so far to an empty array
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        // here you don't need both arr.push(...) and assignment
        arr[i] = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
        
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(createNSizedArray(100));
```

What `Array.prototype.push` does:

```
let arr = [];
console.log(arr);

arr.push(1);
console.log(arr); // [1]

arr.push(2);
console.log(arr); // [1,2]

arr.push(3);
console.log(arr); // [1,2,3]
```

What you're trying to achieve, as @Vincent suggested, can easily be done with:

```
Array(100).fill().map(_ => Math.round(Math.random() * 100))
```

Comment: This is better suited as a comment.

Comment: @Madbreaks I tried to go for a comment first, but seemed to me I would run out of characters, or what do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: Your code comment is literally the explanation: _"(array declaration) had to be moved outside the for-loop"_

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Array method.

```js
    const createNSizeArray = (n) => {
          return Array.from({ length: n }, () => Math.round(Math.random()*100 );
        };
        
    console.log(createNSizeArray(5)) // [81, 92, 23, 54, 12]
```