# How can I display non-repeating random text in a div with an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, math, random

My idea was to make a question and answer card game where when you click on a button you get a random question in a modal, all this works. My question is: How can I do so that the question that already came out does not appear again? for example if I get the question3, that it does not appear again in the whole game.

```
const Arrayorange = [
    {
        question: "question 1",
        reply: "Reply 1",

    },
    {
        question: "question 2",
        reply: "Reply 2",
    },
    {
        question: "question 3",
        reply: "Reply 3",
    }
  ];

export function Orange() {
    const [stateModal, changeStateModal] = useState(false)
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  function openandchange(){
    changeOrange();
    openModal();
  }

  function changeOrange() {
    let newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Arrayorange.length - 0) + 0);
    setIndex(newIndex);
  }
  function openModal(){
    changeStateModal(!stateModal)
  }

  const audio = new Audio(cardsound)


  function openwithsound(){
    openandchange();
    audio.play()
  }

    return (
        <div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={openwithsound}><IoIosBody/></button>

        <ModalOrange
        state={stateModal}
        changeState={changeStateModal}
        titulo="Question"
        
      >
        <Content>
          <h1>{Arrayorange.[index].question}</h1>
          <p>{Arrayorange.[index].reply}</p>
        </Content>
      </ModalOrange>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thank you very much for your answers in advance

Comment: might you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380019/generate-unique-random-numbers-between-1-and-100

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

What I would do, is every time a question gets used, it will get removed from the array, so even if changeOrange() picks the same number again, it can't return the same question.

The method you'll likely want to use is splice

```
Arrayrange = arrayOrange.splice(newIndex, 1)
```

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

And then instead of driving the data on screen with a chosen index of orangeArray, you can just use the sliced question.

Something like this:

```
function changeOrange() {
let newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Arrayorange.length - 0) + 0);
setQuestion(Arrayorange.slice(newIndex, 1)) //this gets the question and puts it in state
Arrayorange = Arrayorange.slice(newIndex, 1) // this ensures the same question can't be chosen ever again
}
```

edit: Changed splice to slice

Comment: you mean `Arrayorange` here ?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Fixed

Comment: you would not use `splice` method until its a copy of state otherwise it mutates the original array and react doesn't know it is changed and won't re-render ...

Comment: @KcH, 
The react rendering isn't driven by the array, it would be driven by a useState that contained a single question.
```const [question, setQuestion] = useState()```
So I'm not sure what issue you're raising here.

Comment: my bad thought Arrayorange is in state, anyways `splice` would change the original array too ...

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'll update to use slice

Comment: So I would have to add a `const [question, setQuestion] = useState()` to my code?

Comment: Yes, for my example to work.

Then instead of ```<h1>{Arrayorange.[index].question}</h1> <p>{Arrayorange.[index].reply}</p>```, You'd do something like ```<h1>{question.question}</h1><h1>{question.reply}</h1> ``` etc