# Javascript: give a variable a name made of 2 variables

Tags: javascript

I want to create a new variable in javascript but it's name should made of a stale part and a variable one like this:

```
tab_counter = 1;
var editor + tab_counter = blabla
```

well i want the new variable name to be in this case editor1, is this possible?

Comment: eval("var editor"+tab_counter);

Comment: Use an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: and then how could i refer to it dinamically?

Comment: @Birey ick :-)  But you're right!

Comment: You know the variable name, it exists right after you eval() it.  http://jsfiddle.net/5ZLYe/

Comment: yes but dinamically, if i don't know the name of the var? i can have tab_counter = 1 or = 1000

Comment: Why do you *need* to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create a stand-alone *variable* name that way (except as a global) (*edit* or except with `eval()`), but you can create an object property:

```
var tab_counter = 1;
var someObject = {};
someObject['editor' + tab_counter] = "bla bla";
```

You can create globals as "window" properties like that, but you probably shouldn't because global variables make kittens cry.

(Now, if you're really just indexing by an increasing counter, you might consider just using an array.)

*edit* also see @Birey's somewhat disturbing but completely correct observation that you can use "eval()" to do what you want.

Comment: All you kind people up-voting me are ignoring the fact that the answer isn't exactly 100% correct as originally written: the "eval()" built-in can do what the OP wants, if he can stomach it!

Comment: I upvoted for your kindness towards kittens. I think the answer sucks :D

Answer (score 2):

It is possible

```
var tab_counter=1;
eval("var editor"+tab_counter+"='blah'")
alert(editor1);
eval("var editor"+tab_counter+1+";")
editor2='blahblah';
alert(editor2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ZLYe/

Comment: You are the creator of your code, you should know your variables. Explain your situation briefly, what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a variable number of tabs in my layout: each time i create a new tab it do tab_counter++ now i want to create a a new var for each tab editor+tab_counter and we're ok. Then the user is in tab number 16 and there is a variable called tab_current = 16; now i want to use editor16 using tab_current, how can i do this?

Comment: @Matteo Have an array called `tabs` and when you create a new tab store a reference to it in `tabs`. eg `tabs[tab_counter] = newTab`.

Comment: When you can create a variable using eval() , you can use it too. 
see last line in : 
http://jsfiddle.net/5ZLYe/1/

Comment: Array would be much better way to do it though.

Comment: +1 For fulfilling the OP's odd requirement but saying Array would be better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `eval` method used by Birey or you can create a custom property of an object such as...

```
obj[editor + tab_counter] = blabla;
```

But it sounds like you're going about doing whatever you're doing in a particularly horrible way. If you just want to store multiple items which you can index into use an array...

```
var array = [];
array[0]  = blabla;
array[1]  = blabla2;

alert(array[0]); //shows value of blabla
alert(array[1]); //shows value of blabla2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may want to consider using a Dictionary for something like this. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208222/how-to-use-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-javascript) which references this [link](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/) describes your options there.