# Efficient way to compare two arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am using two arrays to accomplish a task of checking if values in array1 exist in array2. If so remove the content in array1 and keep checking till array1 is empty. If they dont exist just return from the function. I am using Javascript

I implemented it using classic two for loops which gives a run time of o(n*2). I would like to know if there is any other efficient way to perform this operation using any other data structure that javascript supports. Below is my current implementation

```
for(var j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++){
     for(var k = 0; k < this.probsSolved.length; k++){
         if(tempArray[j] == this.probsSolved[k]){
             tempArray.splice(j,1);            
             if(tempArray.length <= 0){
                 this.updateAchievements(achID);
                 this.storage.set(achKey,1);
                 return;
             }         
     }
}
```

The thing is I have to call the function under which this operation is performed every 5 seconds and this for me looks highly inefficient.

Could someone suggest a better algorithm or a data structure that performs better than the one above that I can use and how would I use if so.

Comment: What is the type of the elements in the arrays? Are the arrays in any particular order?

Comment: The suggested dictionary approach is a good one. Another is to sort both lists and then walk them in order much like you'd do a standard merge. That said, if your lists aren't very large then your "inefficient" method will be plenty fast enough.

Comment: my lists contain integer values and they would at max contain 50 values but the thing is I have to run this operation every 5 seconds. So the searching is practically done every 5 seconds until the first list goes empty. I would look into dictionaries though

Comment: With arrays of max size 50, you're talking a maximum of 2,500 iterations. The time that's going to take will be measured in milliseconds. Doing that once every five seconds will be no problem at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Putting the elements of `array2` in a dictionary data-structure (to ensure that lookup is quick) might help.

See [How to do associative array/hashing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208222/how-do-i-implement-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-javascript)

In pseudo-code, I would approach like the following:

```
dict = {}

foreach elem in array2:
    insert elem in dict

foreeach elem in array1:
    if elem in dict:
        remove elem from array1
```

Comment: `else: return "Not equal"`. And in the end: `if dict not empty: return "Not equal"`

Comment: Thanks I will try using this idea!

Answer (score 8):

Adding an alternative answer, as this will still be relevant to many of us. I found this question when searching for a way to optimise a script that compares two arrays where both have tens of thousands of keys.

In my situation, it forms part of a Google Script, and was exceeding the maximum execution time (~5 minutes) with typical datasets. Making the change below reduced the execution time below 10 seconds.

Inefficient comparison (maximum i*j iterations):

```
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 'd', 'e'];

for (var i in list1) {
    for (var j in list2) {
        if (list1[i] == list2[j]) {
            alert('found ' + list1[i] + ' in both lists');
        }
    }
}
```

Efficient comparison (maximum i+j iterations)

```
var list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 'd', 'e'];
var lookup = {};

for (var j in list2) {
    lookup[list2[j]] = list2[j];
}

for (var i in list1) {
    if (typeof lookup[list1[i]] != 'undefined') {
        alert('found ' + list1[i] + ' in both lists');
        break;
    } 
}
```

Found here: https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/699379-optimize-loops-compare-two-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Based on the other answers, I wrote a TS solution that has the same complexity and is compatible with arrays with repeated elements.

```js
const areArraysEquivalent = <T extends string | number | symbol>(
  a: T[],
  b: T[]
): boolean => {
  const keysAppears: Record<T, number> = {} as Record<T, number>

  for (const key of a) {
    keysAppears[key] = keysAppears[key] ? (keysAppears[key] as number) + 1 : 1
  }

  for (const key of b) {
    if (!keysAppears[key]) {
      return false
    }
    keysAppears[key] = (keysAppears[key] as number) - 1
  }

  return Object.values(keysAppears).every(value => value === 0)
}
```

- ✅ Complexity of N+M
- ✅ Compatible with repeated elements
- ⚠️ Order insensitive
- ❗ Only compatible with types that can be indexes (`number | string | symbol`)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwKYEEELgTwgUQI4CuAlgG5wA2SYsAvDADwAqMSAHlFQCYQzQJFgA5jAA%20MMAQC2AIyQJRvTDJDkAfAAoAsACgY8AFwxGAbQC6AGh17phk6Z0BKQ9JAqkcMDBqqYAbyswoJCwANZI2CgADpHuCBCGAEpIoAicTObiUrIIPnS%20AL7wPEkpaYwZEjJyqjoBAGYg8upB0DBhmDAgdfAOfgF67RBRMYgQxu2mXm3hQ9GxYxMwAPww6oPD8%20Phk3A8ldm9ANQwAIwwhicB%20bW6MA1NLaHhnd3Svf63ekTd6gCE63NRltMKZ3v09DBkFACAhPHUKBAkODrp9phFAXFgZM6GsZhsgYtdpkqghegBaU5XG56KEwzwAeWkACtklAAHRkcgEJAQXHokZxBxspAkOSYdSc7leHySpBeGh0AAMDh0KJ0j14AAsQARyJwAEJIRgIKV0RCodBYXCEUgUKhQdTGE4ZABMGQAzBYYE7XR7QerwBA3GzyCBBOoINrdQajSakCrtAHglqdXrDcbuShyEGpua0BhsPhiJz7Y6AOTgJBljJlqAAdxA1ZgtYbZa9xhbjZrlabnbbCZawdD4cjqZjGdQ2ZACaTrVH0cNADEEXKzch81ai7bKNRHSd286YC7-dpB5QQ2GI1G00hl9n40A)