# How to compare two arrays of objects only once?

Tags: javascript, arrays

**UPDATE**: This question is not a duplicate of suggested [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849384/efficient-way-to-compare-two-arrays), since I want to avoid duplicate calls to `compare`, since it is transitive.

I have two array of objects, say:

```
const A = [
  { id: 1, title: 'alice' },
  { id: 2, title: 'bob' },
  { id: 3, title: 'charlie' },
];

const B = [
  { id: 1, title: 'alice' },
  { id: 3, title: 'charlie' },
  { id: 4, title: 'dasha' },
  { id: 5, title: 'eric' },
];
```

An `id` identifies the object univocally (i.e.: `title` and all other props of an object with a specific `id` are the same for any object in array `A` and `B`).

To compare them I currently do:

```
A.forEach(a => {
  B.forEach(b => {
    compare(a, b);
  })
})
```

The `compare()` function is transitive, so `compare(a, b) === compare (b, a)`.
How can I avoid comparing *twice* the same item?
For example, I want do avoid calling `compare(a.1, b.3)` and then `compare(a.3, b.1)` (where `a.1` is item from array `A` with id `1`).

Comment: Can you share more details? What makes you think that the given code compares anything twice?

Comment: Even after your addition, I don't get your code. If you iterate over `A` in the outer loop, there's no way that the first argument to `compare` can be a value of `B`

Comment: @Liam: no, sorry, I don't thinks so...

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You probably want a modification of the [merge sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). If you google this problem there are LOTS of solutions out there

Comment: @NicoHaase: I'd like to avoid calling `compare(a, b)` for a.id == 1 && b.id == 3 after I did already call  `compare(a, b)` for a.id == 3 && b.id == 1

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? Please share more details by editing your question. In the given example. you would compare each item of A with all items of B only once

Comment: @NicoHaase: sorry, I used a wrong example... Updated my question...

For example, I want do avoid calling `compare(a.1, b.3)` and then `compare(a.3, b.1)` (where `a.1` is item from array `A` with id `1`).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? Is the comparison of that item itself so "expensive" that comparing the ID is sufficient?

Comment: No... The arrays are huge, and I would like comparing the same id's twice, when I already know the answer, since the compare function is transitive... And - most important - I know that  objects ith the same id contain the same data...

Comment: Then: what keeps you from storing such data in any kind of list?

Comment: You're right... That's possibly the right approach... I'm not so confortable using lists (for example, JS `sets`?), unfortunately... I'll better study them in future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make avoid comparision you have to skip than by condition

```
a.id < b.id
```

this mean that you will never compare `a.3  b.3`

but if you will need compare `a.3  b.3`

use a.id <= b.id

```js
const A = [
  { id: 1, title: 'alice' },
  { id: 2, title: 'bob' },
  { id: 3, title: 'charlie' },
];

const B = [
  { id: 5, title: 'eric' },
  { id: 1, title: 'alice' },
  { id: 3, title: 'charlie' },
  { id: 4, title: 'dasha' }
  
];


A.forEach(a => {
  B.forEach(b => {
   if (a.id <= b.id) compare(a, b);
  })
})

function compare(a, b){
 console.log(`compare(${a.id}, ${b.id})`);
}
```

I think you need something like this

```
A.forEach(a => {
  B.forEach(b => {
    if (a.id <= b.id)
       compare(a, b);
  })
})
```

to skip (a.3, b.3)

**Updated**
in case you are not able to compare ID generate hash according
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript). So you will be able to compare by the hash Code

Comment: id's are not necessarily sorted.

Comment: @MarcoS Yes, but you request skip by id. And you comparing only (1,2) (1,3)  and skip comparing (2,1) (3,1)/ no matter their order in array

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: @AzizUmarov: the id's are not numeric in the real life, they are themselves objects with many properties... I can't compare them with a math operator, unfortunately...

Comment: But perhaps I could compare a check-sum of the objects?

Comment: @MarcoS then ok how you will determine equality a.3 b.3

Comment: @MarcoS create hash for each ID and compare then

Comment: @AzizUmarov: the compare function is a costly operation on sub-arrays in `a` and `b`. Sorry for simplyfing too much my question...

Comment: create another object via map and compare them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript

Comment: I know that cost for generating hash is not 0. But you have to injoy something

Comment: @AzizUmarov: yes, perfect... I can stand for a hash creation... Much better than a second `compare`... :-) I'll go that way... If you want to update your answer I'll accept it...

Comment: Sure will update