# 2 unsorted arrays, find if any pairs of values add up to target?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So given 2 unsorted arrays I have to find if any pairs of values (1 from each array) adds up to a target.

In javascript what I did was find the max and min values from array1, then make an array of size `maxVal-minVal`.

I then iterated over array1 and put a 1 at every index of the new array corresponding to the values of array1.

From then I looped through array2 and checked if `newArray[ target - array2[i] ] == 1`

Is this a good solution to this problem?

Comment: What constitutes "a good solution?" Also, it would help us to understand your algorithm better if you provided the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a good solution in terms of speed. However, this is *not* such a great solution in terms of space, because of this

> make an array of size `maxVal-minVal`

When `maxVal-minVal` is large, say, in hundreds of millions, you need to allocate and zero-initialize a very large array. If the two sets of numbers are relatively small, say, a few thousand items, the time it takes to initialize the array may exceed the time it takes to find the solution.

A better approach is to use a hash-based set container in place of an array, because you can run an algorithm without any changes, while memory requirements would be O(N), instead of O(maxVal-minVal).

In JavaScript, an [object can be used as a hash-based container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196101/335858).

Comment: Shoot, that's probably why a couple of my test cases were failing, oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your two unsorted arrays have size M and N. You can run the following algorithm in O(M+N) using a HashSet (a set implemented as a hash table).

Iterate over the first array, and add each value into the HashSet.

Then iterate over the second array, where each item can be referenced as `item[i]`. Because you also know the target value `T`, you know that you are looking for `T - item[i]` from the first array. So for every item `item[i]` in the second array, look for the value `T - item[i]` in the HashSet. If you find such a value, then return true. Otherwise, if you exhaust all the item in the second array, then return false.