# Can you change the same property for more than one variable with one line of code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

If I have many variables with the same property `x`, for example,

```
a.x
b.x
c.x
```

Can I change the value of `x` for all these variables at one time? Something like:

```
*.x = 200; // Change the value of "x" in every variable that has a property "x" to 200.
```

Is it possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Uh, what? What does *`"every variable that has x to 200"`* mean?

Comment: It means whatever this is:
var example = { 
 this: 0,
 andThis: 1
}

Comment: ^ That makes even less sense ?

Comment: @user3055828 can you check my edit to see if it is accurate?

Comment: No, there's really no way to do that, as there is no `*.x` or anything like it. You can iterate and check for properties etc. you can set two variables to the same value, but there's no asterisk selector.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't set multiple variables of the same type at once using a wildcard like you propose.

You can concatenate statements though like this:

```
left.x = right.x = 200;
```

Or use a list or [dictionary like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208222/how-do-i-implement-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-javascript) in javascript and iterate over every key that matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you gather your variables inside a common object like so:

```
var points = { a: { x: 1, y: 2}, b: { x: 3, y: 4 }, c: {x: 5, y, 6 }
```

then it can almost be done (minus the neat wildcard notation). Here's a function that should fit your need:

```
function setPropertyForAll(container, propName, newValue) {
    for (var key in container) {
        if (container.hasOwnProperty(key) && container[key] !== null && container[key].hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
            container[key][propName] = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
setPropertyForAll(points, "x", 42);
```