# Create an associative array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```
var playlist = {"bad romance":"gaga", "we cry":"the script"};
```

How can I get string "gaga" from my code? What is the name of my array in JavaScript programming?

Comment: That structure is invalid in Javascript if I am not mistaken. You are confusing Dictionaries/Maps with Arrays. Try using '{' instead of '(' and you will have a valid dictionary and can access through playlist['bad romance'] which means playlist[key]

Comment: The canonical is *[How to do associative array/hashing in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208222)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Object` instead of `Array`:

```
var playlist = {"bad romance":"gaga", "we cry":"the script"};
alert(playlist["bad romance"]); //gaga
```