# Is there a Dictionary datatype in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript. My need is to use key-value data in it. But I didn't see the dictionary data type in JavaScript. Can somebody help me what is the best data type I should use for this purpose.

Thanks & Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: What is the a problem using a regular object in you use-case? ([How do I implement a Dictionary or Hashtable in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208222/how-do-i-implement-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-javascript))

Answer (score 2):

just use an object:

```
var obj = {};
obj["a"]=5;
console.log(obj["a"]); // 5
```

Comment: You can also write `var obj = {a: 5};`.

Comment: sure, and also obj.a=5; objects are super flexible and usable, and have more methods connected to the "Object" object

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript you can imagine every object as a key-value object.

For your purpose just use the following code:

```
var myDict = {};
myDict.object1 = 42;
```

You can also use numbers and strings as keys:

```
var key = "message";
myDict[key] = "hello";
alert(myDict[key]);

var key2 = 5;
myDict[key2] = "five";
```

I hope that i could help you.

Comment: Given that OP is a beginner, it's worth noting that you don't have to use a variable to store the key; a literal works as well.  Pretty much anything may be used as a key, but it all gets cast to a string, so `myDict[1]` and `myDict["1"]` are the same key.

Comment: Yea but I wrote that you can use for example `myDict.object1 = 42`.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Javascript standard (known as "EcmaScript6") adds a new type called *Map* (see [Mozilla Developer Network - JS API reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) which has less disadvantages than using a simple object.

Here is some code (taken from the website):

```
var myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("myKey", "value associated with 'a string'");
myMap.size; // 1
myMap.get("myKey");    // "value associated with 'a string'"
```

Note that is only supported in newer browsers (see Browser compatibility table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility)).

Comment: Interesting, but I think that a ordinary object is enough for the op, because he seems quite unexperienced...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the quick reply:

I've solve it in this way:

var myCompDetail = {brand:"Dell", model:"Vostro", price:"15k"};

Thanks & Regards,

Abhishek Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Object** data-type for this purpose in JavaScript.

Step-1:
Declare the variable

var car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};

Step-2: Use it wherever required, like below:

car.type, or car.model, or car.color

Hope it will help you.

For more info you can go here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Thanks & Regards,

Arun Dhwaj