# How to corresponding compare list item with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list like this :

```
[EMP004: BPCE-RNHC-25G8, EMP003: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J, EMP005: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ, EMP002: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C, EMP001: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR]
```

**What I trying to achieve:**
User input the first key and then the system will scan through the list and show them corresponding key. For example, if user input "EMP004", it should alert `BPCE-RNHC-25G8` for them.

**Idea:**
How can I separate the first key and second key with `:` ? Other than that how can I know find the corresponding result? Does anyone know how can i solve this with JavaScript only ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an associative array in JavaScript literal notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515959/how-to-create-an-associative-array-in-javascript-literal-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample list you have provided is syntactically incorrect. You can create an array object. Then you can create function that takes the key as the parameter like the following way:

```js
const list = [
  { EMP004: 'BPCE-RNHC-25G8' }, 
  { EMP003: '8FIW-9JRB-NY4J' }, 
  { EMP005: '7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ' }, 
  { EMP002: 'SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C' }, 
  { EMP001: 'PBF7-WZHT-WPZR' }
];
const getValByKey = (key) => Object.values(list.find(o => Object.keys(o)[0] === key ))[0];

console.log(getValByKey('EMP004'));
console.log(getValByKey('EMP002'));
```

**Update:** For string items you can try the following way:

```js
const list = ['EMP004: BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'EMP003: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'EMP005: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'EMP002: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'EMP001: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR'];
const getValByKey = (key) => list.find(item => item.split(':')[0].trim() === key ).split(':')[1].trim();

console.log(getValByKey('EMP004'));
console.log(getValByKey('EMP002'));
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but my list format is `[EMP004: BPCE-RNHC-25G8, EMP003: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J, EMP005: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ, EMP002: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C, EMP001: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR]`. How can i format my current list to your format in order to use this method ?

Comment: @WEIZHUANGGOH, that list syntax is incorrect, from where you are getting that? if list items are in the form of string (`['EMP004: BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'EMP003: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'EMP005: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'EMP002: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'EMP001: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR']`) then only you can format.

Comment: Im getting the list from django `view.py`. By this code `mergedCompare = [item_listAssigned[f'subject{i}']+': '+item_listAssigned[f'serial{i  }'] for i in range(1, len(item_listAssigned)//2+1)]`

Comment: @WEIZHUANGGOH, I have added another answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can do like this:

   function search(arr, sub) {
    sub = sub.toLowerCase();
    matchedIndex = arr.map((str, index) => {
      if (
        str.toLowerCase().startsWith(sub.slice(0, Math.max(str.length - 1, 1)))
      ) {
        return index;
      }
    });
    if(matchedIndex.length>0){
        console.log(matchedIndex);
        matchedIndex = matchedIndex.filter(function( element ) {
            return element !== undefined;
         });
       return matchedIndex[0]
    }
  }
  
  var arr = ["EMP004: BPCE-RNHC-25G8", "EMP003: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J", "EMP005: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ", "EMP002: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C", "EMP001: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR"];
  
  var index = search(arr, 'EMP004');
  if(index>-1){
    matchedvalue=arr[index].split(':');
    console.log(matchedvalue[1]);
  }
  else{
      console.log("Not found")
  }
```

Comment: it only work for `EMP004` but not other key