# How do I not include duplicate values in a React state array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to make sure that I can't push a duplicated value into an array in a React state. The duplicated value is still going in the array though.

I have tried using `.includes` but it is not working.

```
const categoryCheck = (category) => {
  let categories = [...this.state.categories]
  if (this.state.categories === undefined) {
    return
  }
  console.log(categories, category)
  console.log(!categories.includes(category))
  if (!categories.includes(category) === false) {
    categories.push(category)
    console.log('new category', categories)
  } 
}
```

input: `'cat'`

Expected result: `['cat']`
Actual result: `['cat', 'cat']`

UPDATE:
This is my function and this is how I call it. Thanks for all the help!

```
  uniqueCategories = category => {
    //makes sure that there are no duplicate categories in array
    if (category === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    let categories = new Set(category);
    categories = Array.from(categories);
    console.log(categories);
    return categories;
  };
```

I call it in another function like this:

```
  this.setState({
      categories: this.uniqueCategories([
        ...this.state.categories,
        categoryInput
      ])
```

Comment: You can use dictionary as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208222, Or remove duplicated value as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (!categories.includes(category) === false) {
```

is a double negative. Remove the `=== false`.

An alternative is to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for uniqueness since it automatically discards duplicates. Typically, sets offer fast lookup time, but for small amounts of data the performance is probably not much different than array with `includes` since both structures are rebuilt on every render.

Here's a toy example of using `Set`:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState(new Set());
  const [item, setItem] = React.useState("");

  const addCategory = e => {
    if (item.trim()) {
      setCategories(prevState => new Set(prevState).add(item.trim()));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={e => setItem(e.target.value)}
        value={item}
      />&nbsp;
      <button onClick={addCategory}>Add Item</button>
      <ul>{[...categories].map(e => <li key={e}>{e}</li>)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

And an `includes` example:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([]);
  const [item, setItem] = React.useState("");

  const addCategory = e => { 
    const trimmed = item.trim();

    if (trimmed && !categories.includes(trimmed)) {
      setCategories(prevState => prevState.concat(trimmed));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={e => setItem(e.target.value)}
        value={item}
      />&nbsp;
      <button onClick={addCategory}>Add Item</button>
      <ul>{categories.map(e => <li key={e}>{e}</li>)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Example />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` in ES6

```
const categoryCheck = (category) => {
  if (this.state.categories === undefined) {
    return
  }
  let categories = new Set(this.state.categories)
  categories.add(category)
  this.setState({ categories: Array.from(categories) })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is reversed:

```
if (!categories.includes(category) === false) {...}
```

Will return `true` if the item is *not* in the array. Just use this:

```
if (!categories.includes(category)) {...}
```